# How to use a variable as dictionary key using f-string in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, associative-array, f-string

I'm trying to print dictionary item value of a dictionary but my item is also an another user input variable. How can I print the selected value with f-string?

```
option = ''
languages = {'1':'Learn Python', '2':'Learn Java', '3':'Learn C++', '4':'Learn PHP', '5':'Quit'}
option = input('Please choose an option between 1 and 5')

# Following part is not working!!!
print(f'Youve selected {languages["{option}"]}')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
# Following part is working!!!
print(f'Youve selected {languages[option]}')
```

Comment: Yep thanks i think my mistake was to test the variable with a constant like option = 1 but forgot to change it into str() Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need use the next code:

```py
option = input('Please choose an option between 1 and 5')
languages = {'1':'Learn Python', '2':'Learn Java', '3':'Learn C++', '4':'Learn PHP', '5':'Quit'}

print(f'Youve selected {languages[option]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

f-string don't not allow nested interpolation. However, to get the correct option from the dictionary you don't need quotes, `languages[option]` will do.

So the line you are looking to use will be
`print(f"You've selected {languages[option]}")`

Answer (score 0):

option is a variable, but you made option to a string. That means the key you gave the dictionary language is in your case {option} and this key doesnt exist

```
languages = {'1':'Learn Python', '2':'Learn Java', '3':'Learn C++', '4':'Learn PHP', '5':'Quit'}
option = str(input('Please choose an option between 1 and 5'))

# Following part is  working!!!
print(f'Youve selected {languages[option]}')
```

You didnt use the variable option, you used {option} as a string and tried to print the value of the key {option}. Just remove the brackets and the "".

You could also use a f string in a f string, but thats not necessary.

```
print(f'Youve selected {languages[f"{option}"]}')
```

The reason, why your code didnt work is in that case, because you made a string in a f string and not a f string in a f string